# Android ListView JSONObject Question

Tags: java, android, json, listview, adapter

recently I been trying to create an android app that uses JSON Objects to display the title of an RSS feed in a listView. Though what I'm having issues with is the implementation of an listener whenever an item in the listView is touched to display the JSON Object that has the format for the description of the RSS feed stored in it. I have been fiddling with the adapter and had little to no success. Hope someone can help me out.

Here is my RSSActivity class that I made:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;




public class RSSActivity extends ListActivity {

    private RSSListAdapter adapter;
    private int Title = 0;
    private int Description = 1;
    private List<JSONObject> titles = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    private List<JSONObject> descriptions = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        try {
            titles = RSSReader.getLatestRssFeed(Title);
            descriptions = RSSReader.getLatestRssFeed(Description);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
        }

        adapter = new RSSListAdapter(this,titles);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }



    public void makeInfo(Integer pos) {
        Log.i("assetInfo", "=" + pos);

    }



}
```

Here is my RSSListAdapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RSSListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject>{

    private TextView textView;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private int resource;
    private Activity activity;
    public RSSListAdapter(Activity _activity, List<JSONObject> _item) {
        super(_activity, 0, _item);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        activity = _activity;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();

        ViewHolder holder;

        // Inflate the views from XML
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_text_layout, null);


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //The next section we update at runtime the text - as provided by the JSON from our REST call
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            holder.description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            rowView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }


        JSONObject item = getItem(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getJSONObject());

        final OnClickListener titleListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
                TextView tv = (TextView)ll.getChildAt(0);
                Integer pos = (Integer) tv.getTag();
                ((RSSActivity)activity).makeInfo(pos);
            }
        };



        return rowView;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
    }


}
```

and here is my RSSReader class where I build my two separate JSONObjects for the Title of the RSS and the Description of the RSS.

```
import java.util.List;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;


public class RSSReader {

    private final static String BOLD_OPEN = "<B>";
    private final static String BOLD_CLOSE = "</B>";
    private final static String BREAK = "<BR>";
    private final static String ITALIC_OPEN = "<I>";
    private final static String ITALIC_CLOSE = "</I>";
    private final static String SMALL_OPEN = "<SMALL>";
    private final static String SMALL_CLOSE = "</SMALL>";
    private final static int Title = 0;
    private final static int Description = 1;

    /**
     * This method defines a feed URL and then calls our SAX Handler to read the article list
     * from the stream
     * 
     * @return List<JSONObject> - suitable for the List View activity
     */
    public static List<JSONObject> getLatestRssFeed(int value){
        String feed = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/gate6?format=xml";
        int num = value;
        RSSHandler rh = new RSSHandler();
        List<Article> articles =  rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
        Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Number of articles " + articles.size());
        return fillData(articles, num);
    }





    /**
     * This method takes a list of Article objects and converts them in to the 
     * correct JSON format so the info can be processed by our list view
     * 
     * @param articles - list<Article>
     * @return List<JSONObject> - suitable for the List View activity
     * @throws JSONException 
     */
    private static List<JSONObject> fillData(List<Article> articles, int value)  {

        List<JSONObject> items = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        for (Article article : articles) {
            JSONObject currentItem = new JSONObject();
            try {
                if(value == 0)
                {
                    buildJSONObject(article, currentItem, Title);

                }
                else
                {
                    buildJSONObject(article, currentItem, Description);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error creating JSON Object from RSS feed");
            }
            items.add(currentItem);
        }
        return items;

    }


    /**
     * This method takes a single Article Object and converts it in to a single JSON object
     * including some additional HTML formating so they can be displayed nicely
     * 
     * @param article
     * @param current
     * @throws JSONException
     */


    private static void buildJSONObject(Article article, JSONObject current, int value) throws JSONException {

        String text = "";
        String text2 = "";
        if(value == 0)
        {
            text = article.getTitle();
            current.put("text", Html.fromHtml(buildTitle(text).toString()));

        }
        else
        {
            text = article.getDescription();
            text2 = article.getPubDate();
            current.put("text", Html.fromHtml(buildDescription(text, text2).toString()));
        }


    }


    private static StringBuffer buildTitle(String title)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(BOLD_OPEN).append(title).append(BOLD_CLOSE);
        return sb;

    }

    private static StringBuffer buildDescription(String description, String date)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(BREAK);
        sb.append(description);
        sb.append(BREAK);
        sb.append(SMALL_OPEN).append(ITALIC_OPEN).append(date).append(ITALIC_CLOSE).append(SMALL_CLOSE);

        return sb;
    }

}
```

Hope someone can point me into a good direction this will be greatly appreciated since this is my first time doing android development. Let me know if I need to demonstrate something else from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylistically it seems an unnecessary hassle to read in XML RSS feeds and then convert to JSON. JSON is an interchange and storage format, just like XML. I generally use a lightweight forward-reader (SAX reader) for the XML and load the data into plain custom Java objects (POJOs) which are read by the adapter.

Comment: Yeah I just saw a tutorial it seems that SAX would be a better choice. Im going to scrap most of my code and just rebuild it this way. Thanks.